# Weird UIView transforms in Retina iPhone

Tags: ios

I'm having a problem I don't understand. I'm developing an OpenGL app for iOS. Because at some points I want to force the orientation of the view programatically, and Apple for whatever reason doesn't make it easy (or even possible), I'm doing it by hand.

I return always NO in `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, and when I want to change the orientation (to portrait, for example), I do something like this in the UIView:

```
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)];
[self setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
```

This works fine.

In order to support Retina devices, I started checking `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`, and setting `self.contentScaleFactor` accordingly. I also modified the code above to account for the new dimensions, like this:

```
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)];
[self setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2*768, 2*1024)];
```

Same rotation, different size. The weird result with this is that I get a "screen" with the right size, but offsetted half a screen to the bottom and the left. To correct for this, I need to do the following:

```
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)];
[self setBounds:CGRectMake(-768, -1024, 2*768 - 768, 2*1024 - 1024)];
```

This works, but it's ugly, I also need to make similar corrections when I get touch coordinates, and worst of all, I don't understand what's going on or why the above "correction" works.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

### Don't hard-code screen size values!

If you get screen size values from `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`:

- Take the status bar height into account.
- If portrait: set width to screen height and height to screen width

  -- Look at my code to see what I'm talking about: [UIScreen+Flexible category](https://github.com/koreyhinton/UIScreenFlexible).

If you get screen size values from the parent View:

- Make sure you aren't setting any frames before the parent view's frame is set.

Also, Use `setFrame`. I can't think of a case where you should be setting bounds?*

*I may be wrong about bound-setting.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL ES all your transformation need to be make on OpenGL ES context.
And on your view layer you need to set scaleFactor on view object which is GLKView type.

```
view.contentScaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

And do not forget to set the glViewPort.

```
glViewport(0,
           0,
           _screenWidth*self.view.contentScaleFactor,
           _screenHeight*self.view.contentScaleFactor);
```